# find The convergence value of an iterative process

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I recently encountered an iterative process at work. Through program simulation, I can guess that the iterative process can iterate to a value, but I can't find its specific convergence value. I would like to ask for advice. Grateful!

Q:It is known that: $a, b, c, d, e$ are all rational numbers greater than 0. The iteration process is as follows
$$
x_0 = a \\
x_1 = \frac {n*x_0*b + n*c + 2*d} {n*x_0*b + n*c + 2*x_0*e} x_0 \\
...\\
x_n = \frac {n*x_{n-1}*b + n*c + 2*d} {n*x_{n-1}*b + n*c + 2*x_{n-1}*e} x_{n-1}
$$
So does $x_n$ converge to a certain value? Convergence to what value?

This problem may also be transformed into finding the iteration function
$$
f(x)=\frac {ax+b} {cx+d} x
$$
general formula.

Use programs to perform simulation calculations:

```
/**
This program variable corresponds to:
a:C/B
b:b
c:b
d:d
e:e
n:n
x:v
By modifying the value of n, this program finds that v will tend to a certain value. As n gets larger and larger, it tends to a certain value and becomes smaller and smaller from a certain value. It is guessed that it should be able to converge to a certain value. . This situation will still happen if a, b, c, d are continuously transformed. So I guess that the iterative process should be able to converge to a certain value, but I don't know what value it will converge to.
*/

const B = 10000
const C = 100000
const n = 10000000

function _commulate_(e:number,d:number) {
    var c = C
    var b = B
    var last_x = 0
    var x = (C)/(B)
    for(let i = 0;i<n;i++){
        var b_0 = e / n
        var c_0 = d / n
        var last_x = x
        x = x*(x*b+c+2*c_0) / (x*b+c+2*b_0*x)
    }

    console.log(x,last_x-x)
}
_commulate_(10000,10000)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the shortened form you can see that $x=0$ is a fixed point. The other point can be found from the condition $$ax+b=cx+d$$ after cancelling the now non-zero $x$ from the fixed-point equation $x=f(x)$.

It remains to explore the stability of these points.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to find the possible values of the limit, should it exist. Denoting $L = \lim x_n$, you can see that
$$
L = \dfrac{n b L + nc+2d}{nbL+2eL + nc} L
$$

So, as it was mentioned before, $L=0$ is a possibility. If $L \ne 0$, one must have

$$
nbL+nc+2d=nbL+2eL+nc \Leftrightarrow d = eL \Leftrightarrow L =d/e.
$$

The stability of these fixed points is another issue... Depending on the choice of $x_0$ and on the particular values of the parameters, the sequence may, in principle, not converge at all.

After a few numerical experiments, $L=0$ seems to be unstable. Even when your start with a small value of $x_0$, the sequence still converges to $d/e$. I was unable to produce divergent sequences, but this is by no means a proof of stability of $L = d/e$.